# Jenkins git clone fails intermittently

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

We clone three repos in our pipeline from `BitBucket`:

1. Shared Libraries
2. Jenkinsfile
3. Source code

The build fails intermittently with logs shown below:

```
Started by an SCM change
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://bitbucket-server/scm/xxxx/xxxx.git
 > git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket-server/scm/xxxx/xxxx.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Obtained Jenkinsfile from c310abe88924c711a29be22b659dd719ac680942
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
Loading library utilities@xxxx
Attempting to resolve xxxx from remote references...
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote ssh://git@xxxx/xxxx/jenkins-libraries.git # timeout=10
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote ssh://git@xxxx:xxxx/xxxx/jenkins-libraries.git" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Terminated
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1666)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1657)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRemoteReferences(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2877)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:806)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:617)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.lambda$retrieve$0(SCMSourceRetriever.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrySCMOperation(SCMSourceRetriever.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.retrieve(LibraryAdder.java:157)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.add(LibraryAdder.java:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryDecorator$1.call(LibraryDecorator.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.lambda$doParse$0(CpsGroovyShell.java:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.lambda$doParse$0(CpsGroovyShell.java:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

On triggering the same job manually after some time, it succeeds. I do not mean to say here that the poll scm is the issue. Sometimes it succeeds. We are using Jenkins in master - slave configuration. For the master, `jenkins/jenkins:2.168` image is used and `jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.10-1` for slave. This entire setup is running on Azure Kubernetes Service and deployed through `Helm`. For git, we use [Git plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) version 3.9.3

Comment: Are you shure is not a DNS issue?

Comment: Yes. I am positive.

Comment: Pasting the URL of the same problem posted on Jenkins Issue Tracker: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56593

Comment: UPDATE: We were able to solve this error by cloning via https instead of SSH. The issue has not reappeared since. We are not sure why it worked. We are not investigating this. I'd be happy to answer any questions around this.